# Run a model in production schema from development environment

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, jinja2, dbt, dbt-cloud

We are in dbt Cloud. Many times (especially for incremental models) I would like to run a model only one time with a specific set of parameters, which I don't want to push into the main branch. I would like to test a `dbt run` in a development environment and then I would like to run the same code in production. Same, meaning that all the `ref()` functions and so on use the production schema instead.

Comment: Are you using BigQuery in your use case? If so, could you elaborate on your use case?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT I can explain more my use case, but that is completely not relevant to this question. It uses BigQuery as a backend, but the solution for this post has to be done in dbt, I believe.